# Cannot start jenkins after changed keystore password

Tags: jenkins

I changed my keystore password today to a more secure one and I cannot restart jenkins. The log has the following error:

```
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:207)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:149)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:246)
        at Main.main(Main.java:91)
Caused by: winstone.WinstoneException: Error getting the SSL context object
        at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.getSSLContext(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:241)
        at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.createConnector(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:131)
        at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.start(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:116)
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:205)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
        at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:146)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:96)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
        at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:133)
        at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:70)
        at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256)
        at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.getSSLContext(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:210)
```

I am assuming the password was stored somewhere and now they don't jive...

Comment: Check in JENKINS_HOME config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out something got screwed up with keystore when I used a 3d party utility to combine a couple of certificates and change the password. I cleaned all that up and all is fine again.